# Google Maps marker DROP

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to drop my markers one after another instead of dropping all them at the same time. My `drop function()` does not seem to be working here. I do not know what is wrong. Please take a look at my code.

```
<script>

function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(63.417622, 10.404316);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 13,
center: myLatlng
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var marker;


var locations = [];
   locations.push ({name: "1", p: new google.maps.LatLng(63.417622, 10.404316)});
   locations.push ({name: "2", p: new google.maps.LatLng(63.409868, 10.446512)});
   locations.push ({name: "3", p: new google.maps.LatLng(63.429070, 10.390894)});
   locations.push ({name: "4", p: new google.maps.LatLng(63.437208,10.452692)});

   function addMarker(){
      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: locations[i].p, map: map, title: locations[i].name, icon: 'cabin_icon.png', animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP});          
    }
   } //This put my markers on the map all at once.

//Function to drop them at one after another after a few milliseconds.

   function drop (){
    for (var j = 0; j < locations.length; j++) {
      setTimeout( function(){
        addMarker();
      }, j * 200);
    };
   }; //But this function is not working. Markers are not even showing up after I have created this function.

} 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); </script>
```

I have tried to edit the code in many different ways but could not get it right. I tried with [Google tutorial on this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration) too and have no luck with the code either. So I need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *drop* function is declared inside the *initialize* function, which means you need to call it before the end of *initialize* or place it outside *initialize*.

What your drop function does now is that it drops all markers 4 times with a delay.

What you want to do is probably something like this:

```
function initialize(){

...


function addMarker(i){
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: locations[i].p, map: map, title: locations[i].name, icon: 'cabin_icon.png', animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP});   
}

function drop(){
   for (var j = 0; j < locations.length; j++) {
      setTimeout(function(i){addMarker(i)}, 200*j, j);
   }
}

drop();
}
```